# How to save plotly dash Input as global variable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard using Plotly Dash that requires data to be filtered by date (sliders don't work since some charts are categorical).

I would like to allow the user to input a date which I would then use as a global variable. I import this global variable to filter my dataframes in other python files, and then create the charts. My attempt below doesn't work; the variable `start_date` does not update.

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='date', value='start date (yyyy-mm-dd)', type='text'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button', type='submit', children='Submit'),
    html.Div(id='output_div')
])

start_date = 0

@app.callback(Output('output_div', 'children'),
                [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('date', 'value')],
                )
def update_output(clicks, input_value):
    if clicks:
        print(clicks, input_value)
        global start_date
        start_date = datetime.strptime(input_value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        return start_date
        print(type(start_date))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of what your final goal is, but you can initialize an empty and *hidden* `html.Div(...)`, and later use it to store the input from the callback. After that you will be able to access to it from any other callback.

Comment: How would you extract the value from the hidden Div and assign it to a variable?

Comment: I mean that you can use it as input for other callbacks - for instance those in which you filter and dataframes and create charts